List out of range error using imaplib to search for a specific query
Why does my script below give me index out of range error while trying to excute the for statement.
Cant seem to figure it out.
When I use ALL as query this works.
Also notice that first email no & last email no is being correctly retreived.
import imaplib
import email
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Listbox, Scrollbar, messagebox
import webbrowser
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Your Gmail credentials
FROM_EMAIL = "xxx@gmail.com"
FROM_PWD = "xxx xxx xxx xxx"

# Connect to Gmail IMAP server
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT = 993
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD)

mail.select("INBOX")
 
# Search for emails received today
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)
query = f"(BEFORE \"{today.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')}\") (SINCE \"{yesterday.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')}\")"
print(query)

# results = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
results = mail.search(None, query)

# results = mail.search(None, 'before:', today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), ' after:', yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
# mail_ids = results[1][0].split()
mail_ids = results[1]
id_list = mail_ids[0].split()   
first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])

print(first_email_id)
print(latest_email_id)

# Create a GUI window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Today's Emails")

# Create a list box
email_listbox = Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
email_listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Fetch email details and populate the list box
# for i in range(len(mail_ids)):

for i in range(latest_email_id, first_email_id - 1, -1):
        try:
            email_id = int(id_list[i])
        except IndexError:
            print(f"Index {i} is out of range.")
        
        data = mail.fetch(str(email_id), '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])')
        for response_part in data:
            arr = response_part[0]
            if isinstance(arr, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(str(arr[1], 'utf-8'))
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_from = msg['from']
                email_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"From: {email_from} | Subject: {email_subject}")

# Function to open the selected email in the default browser
def open_email(event):
    selected_index = email_listbox.curselection()
    if selected_index:
        email_id = int(mail_ids[selected_index[0]])
        webbrowser.open(f"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/{email_id}")

# Bind double-click event to open_email function
email_listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", open_email)

# Run the GUI
root.mainloop()


Just trying to list all emails received today in my gmail inbox on a window.

Please post the full traceback so we can see where this is happening.

Why do you convert email_id to an integer, then change it back to a string when you call mail.fetch()? Just use the original ID as it is.
